What is the alternative for instagram basic display api since its deprecated
The Instagram Basic Display API was deprecated on 4th September and when I checked for other alternatives for third party application login (React in my case) it showed a Instagram app for Business accounts as API setup with Instagram Login & API setup with Facebook Login. I am currenlty learning the process but I don't know how these work. I just need a Login handler after which my app has access to user data (followers, following, etc.)

I do not know why they are doing this, but they seem only to allow apps that serve "professional" accounts through the APIs. It basically means that your users need to have either a business or creator account.
This totally makes no sense for consumer apps, and it may possibly shut them down.
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2024/09/04/update-on-instagram-basic-display-api/
In the above article they released, they have clearly written:

After December 4th, 2024, there will no longer be a set of Instagram
APIs for consumer developer apps.

This possibly means that they have no intention to release another equivalent API for consumer developer apps.
And they just confused the developers coming to their documentation by stating:

Starting December 4, 2024, all requests to the Instagram Basic Display
API will return an error message. We recommend that you migrate your
app to the Instagram API to avoid any disruption to your services.

My personal opinion is that this will disrupt the services of consumer developer apps and there are no APIs to serve Instagram personal accounts (as of 22nd September 2024).
However if you do find an alternative, please comment so we can know about it.

I'm speechles. This's unacceptable in an AI world.

It looks like they will not be offering a login for normal IG user accounts any more, only for "professional" accounts - Businesses and Creators.
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2024/09/04/update-on-instagram-basic-display-api/:

After December 4th, 2024, there will no longer be a set of Instagram APIs for consumer developer apps.

If your use case are business/creator accounts - then you have the choice between the Instagram API with Instagram Login and the Instagram API with Facebook Login. The API with IG Login does not require a Facebook Page to be linked to the Instagram professional account.

Yeah I tried using the API with instagram Login but I didn't got too far with that, can you link me with a proper impementation or a way to use the same

No, I can't link you to any specific implementation. What steps need to be performed is explained in the documentation though.

Yeah I followed almost everything in the documentation, but when I started impementing things dont go the right way. Also I used npm libraries for login buttons but that didn't work too

We can't help much, based on "things dont go the right way." You'll need to properly explain what you're trying to do, and what the problem is, if you want help with those issues. You should probably ask a new, dedicated question for that though.

In the API setup with Instagram business login section there a re 4 steps to complete

Generate access tokens
Configure webhooks
Set up Instagram business login
Complete app review (pending in my case due to verification of a business name which I don't have)

I am assuming that after these steps I will be able to login users to my site with the help of appId and appSecret which I tried
`<InstagramLogin authCallBack={responseFn} appId="..." appSecret="..." redirectUri={url}

`

but this shows error invalid response type

I have still not completed the 4th step, its in process
