Replacement for Instagram Basic Display API after its deprecation?
Instagram announced that the Instagram Basic Display API will be deprecated soon. I have been using it to fetch basic profile information, posts, and other public data from Instagram.
Has anyone found a simple replacement for the Instagram Basic Display API that can achieve similar functionality?
Any recommendations would be appreciated.

It seems they are not providing a new solution for consumers. If you have a professional account there might be a solution by using Instagram API with Instagram Login or Instagram API with Facebook Login.
Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78977319/what-is-the-alternative-for-instagram-basic-display-api-since-its-deprecated
Documentation from Meta: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2024/09/04/update-on-instagram-basic-display-api/
